# CNAMEレコードで追加したサブドメインにpingが通らない

Tags: dns

以下のようなDNSレコード設定をmuumuuドメインで行っていました。

```
,A,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
*,CNAME,example.com
```

(設定画面のテキストボックスをカンマ区切りで表しています。)

この状態で`foo.example.com`ブラウザではサイトにアクセスできていたのですが`ping`を試すと`ping: cannot resolve foo.example.com: Unknown host`のエラーになってしまいました。

結局以下のように全てAレコードで設定すれば`ping`の名前解決が働きました。

```
,A,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
foo,A,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
bar,A,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

CNAMEレコードで設定すると何故`ping`が通らなかったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

ping実行時の名前解決に利用したDNSサーバーがコンテンツサーバーだったのではないでしょうか。
ping実行時の名前解決にキャッシュサーバーを利用すれば解決するのでは？
cnameの設定先はコンテンツサーバーですが、アクセス時の名前解決に利用するのはキャッシュサーバーにするべきです。役割も挙動も違います。
[コンテンツサーバとキャッシュサーバ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90#%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%84%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%81%A8%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90)

Answer (score -1):

[CNAME record, dig and nslookup are ok, but can't ping #1840](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/1840)

Comment: 確かにリンクが回答の一部になっている可能性がありそうですが、一応日本語のQAサイトですので要約で結構ですので日本語で解説や回答をいただけるとよりよい回答になると思います。